# What phase is water at 262C and 15bar?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, phase-transition

what phase is water at 262C and 15bar? at which conditions and above can we be sure that the water is totally gaseous? can I see a water phase graph for 262C and 15bar?

Comment: Have you even looked anywhere for this? The phase diagram on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram#Crystal_phase_diagrams) is pretty clear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: No it's not clear. What is the answer? And don't vote to close my question! It's ridiculous!

Comment: I hold the belief that at such conditions, we can have both liquid and gas! Is that correct or not?

Comment: Okay, so let's break this down. Are you having trouble reading the phase diagram -- like when you pick the conditions you listed, you can't physically find them in the diagram? Or are you having trouble interpreting what it means when a conditions falls on the black line between two or more phases? Can you be maybe more specific about what isn't clear for you when you look at a phase diagram?

Comment: I am looking for a diagram that looks like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/TS-Wasserdampf_engl.png and will show the phases at 262C and 15bar. Can you find any?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't read a phase diagram, a good set of steam tables can answer your question.

BTW, water can only exist as a vapor and a liquid in equilibrium when conditions place it below the saturation line.  For a pressure of 15 bar (1.5 MPa) absolute, the saturation temperature is 198.3 C.  At this pressure, only superheated vapor exists at temperatures greater than 198.3 C.

Sorry, but you're going to have to alter your beliefs.

Comment: Do you have a T-phase diagram that shows that?

Comment: Because I see in that diagram https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/TS-Wasserdampf_engl.png that above 200C the water can be still between liquid and gas form.

Comment: No, you are reading the T-s diagram wrong.  The big red line is the saturation line.  Above it, you have only superheated vapor.  Below it, you have liquid and vapor in equilibrium with one another.  You have to read the top bit at P = 15 bar (blue line).  Come down this line to the red (saturation) line and you'll see it intersects at about 200 C.  This is the saturation temperature for a liquid-vapor mixture.

Comment: Yes. But the tricky part is that in order to see what happens at the same pressure 15bar, above the temperature 200C, you cannot just go up the y axis vertically. Instead, you can go up along the pressure line! That was my problem. Isn't it tricky? I thought that above the 200C there is also an area of liquid/gas mixture, but that corresponds to different/higher pressure. To see the water at 15bar above 200C, you follow the 15bar blue line with above 200C goes outside the liquid/gas mixture phase, into the superheated area. Tell me honestly, isn't that tricky?

Comment: That's why most thermo courses have you spend a certain amount of time reading charts of thermo properties.  P-h and T-s diagrams are common, and one type of chart may be easier to use to solve certain problems.  For example, h-s charts, called Mollier diagrams for water/steam, are commonly used to figure out problems involving steam turbines.